# Notation: what is the purpose of shortened & barred tack variants?

Tags: logic, notation

I hope this is the right place for this question; I couldn't seem to find a better community for it, but if anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.

I'm familiar with the down tack ($\top$) and up tack ($\bot$) symbols in the context of mathematical logic. However, when searching for their Unicode values, I came across [many](https://graphemica.com/search?q=tack) other tack variants. I'm especially curious about the [shortened](https://graphemica.com/%E2%AB%A0) (e.g. ⫠) and [barred](https://graphemica.com/%E2%AB%A8) (e.g. ⫨) versions of them. Do those variations on the tack symbols imply any change in meaning? I couldn't find them used anywhere.

Comment: The "barred tack" is often used in [forcing arguments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)) when turned on its side.

Comment: See [Turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)) and [Double turnstile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA are those symbols related to the tack variants I mentioned?

Comment: The answer is probably either: it is a very particular notation used in some subfield or they were just added for completeness.